# How to navigate from the used component to another component, from a method?

Tags: angular

I have a router module look like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '', component: Item1Component,
    children: [
      {path: '', redirectTo: 'item1', pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: 'item2', component: Item2Component}
    ]
  }
];
```

Now I want to navigate from `Item1Component` to `Item2Component`, so I use:

```
open() {
  this.router.navigate(['/item2']);
}
```

It doesn't redirect me to the correct url, but when I use :

```
this.router.navigate(['/item1/item2']);
                        ^^^^^
```

It redirect me to the correct url.

Is there any way to combine my `item2` with `item1`, without hard coded this?

I tried:

```
this.router.navigate(['/item2', {relativeTo: this.route}]);
```

But this do another thing.

Comment: item2 is the child of item1 so the path is correct all you need remove item2 from children and add to root level.

Comment: Thank you @KamranKhatti the root I share is a part of parent root, so in the real life I have `parent/item1/item2` so even I remove item2 from children, I still need to put `/parent/item2` to call my component

Comment: In such case for what is {redirectTo: 'item1' }?

Comment: Remove `{path: '', redirectTo: 'item1', pathMatch: 'full'}` from children and then try again if not work then move this to root level

Comment: @itspers I just try it and it doesn't give me what I need, I thought it combine the current root with the called root

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets say `Item1Component` is defined in Item1ComponentModule. Than according to your route `Item2Component` is a child of `Item1ComponentModule`. Thats why `this.router.navigate(['/item1/item2']);` is working.

If you want `this.router.navigate(['/item2']);` to work, than define `Item2Component` in its own module(eg- Item2ComponentModule) along with its Routes.

```
                    |----Item1Component
So, PARENT-Route ---|
                    |----Item2Component
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer, I was thinking for this, and I thought there are a sneaky way to avoid creating a module for Item2

Comment: Modules are a great way to organise our code physically as well as logically. Routing is one of the features it provide. Never sneak to avoid 

Answer (score 0):

Please try this.

```
this.router.navigate(['/item2'], {relativeTo: this.activatedRoute});
```